# How to store multiple float arrays efficiently in a file using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle

I am trying to extract embeddings from a hidden layer of LSTM. I have a huge dataset with multiple sentences and therefore those will generate multiple numpy vectors. I want to store all those vectors efficiently into a single file. This is what I have so far

```py
with open(src_vectors_save_file, "wb") as s_writer, open(tgt_vectors_save_file, "wb") as t_writer:
    for batch in data_iter:
        encoder_hidden_layer, decoder_hidden_layer = self.extract_lstm_hidden_states_for_batch(
            batch, data.src_vocabs, attn_debug
        )
        encoder_hidden_layer = encoder_hidden_layer.detach().numpy()
        decoder_hidden_layer = decoder_hidden_layer.detach().numpy()

        enc_hidden_bytes = pickle.dumps(encoder_hidden_layer)
        dec_hidden_bytes = pickle.dumps(decoder_hidden_layer)

        s_writer.write(enc_hidden_bytes)
        s_writer.write("\n")
        t_writer.write(dec_hidden_bytes)
        t_writer.write("\n")
```

Essentially I am using `pickle` to get the `bytes` from the `np.array` and writing that in binary file. I tried to naively separate each byte encoded array with ASCII newline which obviously throws an error. I was planning to use `.readlines()` function or read each byte-encoded array per line using a `for` loop in the next program. However, that won't be possible now.

I am out of any ideas can someone suggest an alternative? How can I efficiently store all the arrays in a compressed fashion in one file and how can I read them back from that file?

Comment: The [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) seems to be what you're looking for here - make a type for each float in a fixed number of bytes, concatenate each array of floats into one tightly-packed line, and then write those bytes to the file

Comment: I can't keep all the arrays into the memory at one point as they are very big (n_words, 500) dimensional. Is any way where I can binarize one array at a time and mark them with some separator? Also how can I read them back if I do this?

Comment: You would read them back by doing the same thing in reverse - read in `wb` mode, and convert bytes into floats. You can handle only one list at a time by using loops (which you're already doing in your `for` loop, it looks like). Using `\n` as a separator is probably fine, but you would want to experiment a bit to make sure it works.

Comment: Stop adding the newlines. `readlines` will not work, since a pickle binary dump isn't text, so semantically that is nonesense. You just use `pickle.load` repeatedly on the file handler opened in binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with using `\n`s are separators because the dump from pickle (`enc_hidden_bytes`) could have `\n` in it because the data is not ASCII encoded.

There are two solutions. You can escape the `\n` appearing in the data and then use `\n` as terminators. But this adds complexity even while reading.

The other solution is to put into the file the size of the data before starting the actual data. This is like some sort of a header and is a very common practice while sending data over a connection.

You can write the following two functions -

```
import struct

def write_bytes(handle, data):
        total_bytes = len(data)
        handle.write(struct.pack(">Q", total_bytes))
        handle.write(data)

def read_bytes(handle):
        size_bytes = handle.read(8)
        if len(size_bytes) == 0:
            return None
        total_bytes = struct.unpack(">Q", size_bytes)[0]
        return handle.read(total_bytes)
```

Now you can replace

```
s_writer.write(enc_hidden_bytes)
s_writer.write("\n")
```

with

```
write_bytes(s_writer, enc_hidden_bytes)
```

and same for the other variables.

While reading back from the file in a loop you can use the `read_bytes` function in a similar way.